# Convert array of doubles to list object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following array of coordinates:

```
double[] points = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Then I have the following class:

```
public class clsPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

I need to copy the points into List objects.  Where the first point in the array is the X and the second point in the array is the Y.  Here is what I have so far but it is not correct:

```
List<clsPoint> lstPoints = points
                           .Select(coord => new clsPoint
                           {
                               X = coord[0],
                               Y = coord[1]
                           }).ToList();
```

**Expected Results**

```
clsPoint Objects List (lstPoints)
X = 1 , Y = 2
X = 3 , Y = 4
X = 5 , Y = 6
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to use Linq for this case? Normally this is only 3 lines of code, with creating new clsPoints instances and assigning properties with values from array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a sequence of consecutive values until the half your array, then you can project using those values as index to get the pairs.

```
var result=Enumerable.Range(0, points.Length / 2).Select(i=>new clsPoint{X=points[2*i],Y=points[2*i+1]});
```

### Update

This is another solution using `Zip` extension method and one overload of `Where` extension method to get the index:

```
var r2 = points.Where((e, i) => i % 2 == 0)
               .Zip(points.Where((e, i) => i % 2 != 0), (a, b) => new clsPoint{X= a, Y= b });
```

Comment: @TravisJ, you are right, I just edited my answer with another solution

Comment: Octavio, thanks unique solution and works for this problem!

Comment: I would appreciate to the people who downvote my first solution (which was wrong) check this new one.

Answer (score 2):

Using the overload of `Select` that receives the current index you can set a grouping rule (in this case a different id for each 2 numbers), then group by it and eventually create your new `clsPoint`:

```
double[] points = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var result = points.Select((item, index) => new { item, index = index / 2 })
                   .GroupBy(item => item.index, item => item.item)
                   .Select(group => new clsPoint { X = group.First(), Y = group.Last() })
                   .ToList();
```

Doing it with a simple `for` loop would look like:

```
List<clsPoint> result = new List<clsPoint>();
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i += 2)
{
    result.Add(new clsPoint { X = points[i], Y = points.ElementAtOrDefault(i+1) });
}
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if it explained how the code solves the OP's question...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan -Agree :) was just typing :)

Comment: And if you remove the redundant `for` loop curly braces, what we got? 3- liner vs 4-liner inefficient and unreadable LINQ :) Also I would never use the weird `ElementAtOrDefault`.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I agree with you that it is better than the linq and that is why I added the `for`.

Comment: Awesome job Gilad.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is probably a better way for you to compose your points prior to feeding them into your class. A simple for loop may suffice better in this situation as well.

However, in LINQ, you would first use a projection to gather the index so that you could group based on pairs and then use a second projection from the grouping to populate the class.

It looks like this

```
points.Select((v,i) => new { 
    val = v, 
    i = i 
}).GroupBy(o => o.i%2 != 0 ? o.i-1 : o.i).Select(g => new clsPoint() {
    X = g.First().val,
    Y = g.Last().val
});
```